# jQueryプラグインのperfect-scrollbarの仕組みについて

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQueryプラグインのperfect-scrollbar

http://noraesae.github.io/perfect-scrollbar/

はどういう仕組みでスクロールさせているのか教えてください。ほかのよくあるスクロールバーをカスタマイズできるプラグインだと、HTML上に `style="top:10px"` みたいな感じでスクロール分が更新されていくのですが、perfect-scrollbarだけはどうも違うようなのです。しかも、すごくなめらかにスクロールできます。
もしわかる方がいればよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ターゲットの要素に `overflow: hidden;` スタイルを足して、`要素.scrollTop = ...` `要素.scrollLeft = ...` でスクロール位置を操作しています。